# laravel pusher error api key not in cluster

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher

I tried using the pusher on Laravel to make a realtime notification, 41/5000
I have entered the app key into env but I got an error like this

```
        {  
           "type":"WebSocketError",
           "error":{  
              "type":"PusherError",
              "data":{  
                 "code":4001,
                 "message":"App key API_KEY_HERE not in this cluster. Did you forget to specify the cluster?"
              }
           }
        }
```

someone please help me thanks

Answer (score 3):

I too encountered this error when I first used Pusher with Laravel. You have most likely set a different cluster location in Pusher than Laravel's default.

In `.env` make sure you have `PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER` set to the cluster you chose when you first created your app, such as `eu`, `mt1`, `us1`, etc.

You can also edit this setting in `config/broadcasting.php` along with the rest of Pusher's settings.

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

add cluster value when calling pusher in the client

```
var pusher = new Pusher('************', {
      cluster: 'us2'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Same problem, I have solved this one by providing the `PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER` value from pusher's `cluster` value.
I mean, in pusher `App keys` section, they provide a `cluster` value.
That resolves my issue.